# Angular UI Bootstrap Popover - How to close an popover with ESC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover

I searched the questions and answers, tried different approaches (e.g. `$('#element').popover('hide')`) and I am still unable to close a Bootstrap popover with ESC button.

I would (falsely) assume this should work

```
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.which === 27) {
      alert( "esc");
      $scope.isOpen = false;
    }
});
```

, but it is not.

I prepared [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9jLLm0?p=preview).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want to close it only on esc press ?

Comment: Other ways how to close the popover (clicking outside, buttons etc) are working. So closing on esc press is enough here, thanks.

Comment: Check the plunker to see it working.

Comment: ng-keypress may be an option too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aran said, this is related to the digest cycle issue as the change is not detected by angular.

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/M3F7dmmLBrtGdBCICdLm?p=preview

Make sure to use $scope.$digest as it will automatically enforce $apply

```
$scope.save = function () {
  $scope.isOpen = false;
  $scope.$digest();
};

$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.which === 27) {
      $scope.save();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, move your logic to your controller. Then add `$scope.$apply()` to force a `$digest` cycle (you are using `jQuery` which is a 3rd party, not an angular built-in mechanism).

Like this:

**controller**

```
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.which === 27) {
          $scope.isOpen = false;
          $scope.$apply();
       }
    });
```